Map Extension Quirk - why is the lines parameter interpreted strangely depending on ASK or direct parameter setting
At my personal wiki https://ebike.bitplan.com/index.php/Saaleradweg2024-09 we document our bike trips. We have setup "Tour", "Leg" and "Loc" Templates and Forms for this and corresponding properties. We then want to show the Tour Legs in a map using https://maps.extension.wiki/wiki/Maps_for_MediaWiki e.g.:

Which would be based on setting the lines in
{{#display_map:
|lines={{trim|{{{lines|}}}}}
~{{{title|Legs}}}
~{{{subtitle|from subobjects}}}
~{{{color|blue}}}
~{{{opacity|0.42}}}
~{{{line_width|15}}}
|center={{{center|}}}
|zoom={{{zoom|12}}}
|width={{{width|800}}}
|height={{{height|600}}}
|fullscreen=on
|service={{{service|leaflet}}}}}

to
50.193208° N, 11.770475° E: 50.119264° N, 11.828753° E:

50.119264° N, 11.828753° E: 50.308897° N, 11.923706° E:

50.308897° N, 11.923706° E: 50.399850° N, 11.717814° E:

50.399850° N, 11.717814° E: 50.447664° N, 11.639817° E:

50.447664° N, 11.639817° E: 50.606114° N, 11.649306° E:

50.606114° N, 11.649306° E: 50.890000° N, 11.584583° E:

50.890000° N, 11.584583° E: 51.105525° N, 11.675292° E:

51.105525° N, 11.675292° E: 51.362558° N, 11.264322° E:

see https://ebike.bitplan.com/index.php/Template:LegMapLines
this works ok when we set these value verbatim. If they come from an SMW ask query as in
https://ebike.bitplan.com/index.php/Template:LegMap
The result looks strange:

and is always the same wrong line. The only difference we could find so far is visible in the debug output:

50.119264° N, 11.828753° E: 50.308897° N, 11.923706° E:

50.308897° N, 11.923706° E: 50.399850° N, 11.717814° E:

50.399850° N, 11.717814° E: 50.447664° N, 11.639817° E:

50.447664° N, 11.639817° E: 50.606114° N, 11.649306° E:

50.606114° N, 11.649306° E: 50.890000° N, 11.584583° E:

50.890000° N, 11.584583° E: 51.105525° N, 11.675292° E:

51.105525° N, 11.675292° E: 51.362558° N, 11.264322° E: ← 

There are two extra blank chars  - otherwise we could find no difference in the input. It is byte for byte exactly the same but the result is different.
This is a surprising quirk ..
What might be the reason for this strange behavior?
How can we fix this?
Please note that the behavior is the same for different Versions of the Map extension.
8.0.0 has the same behavior as 9.0.7
see e.g.
http://playground-mw.bitplan.com/Phobos/index.php?title=Via_Verde_del_Plazaola

Reminds me of https://github.com/ProfessionalWiki/Maps/issues/652
